# how to reset apfs disk volume uuid on macos?

Tags: uuid, apfs

I had try followed:
apfs.utils  -k  /dev/disk1s5
uuid returned.
apfs.utils  -s  /dev/disk1s5
but uuid not changed.
Does any other way to reset the uuid of the disk volume?